# What's the difference between these two requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Why does the first request return 200,

```
fetch("https://api.peopledatalabs.com/v5/autocomplete?api_key=someAPIKey&field=location")
```

but the second returns 400/401?

```
fetch(`https://api.peopledatalabs.com/v5/autocomplete`, {
    "api_key": "someAPIKey",
    "field": "location"
    });
```

Comment: because the object is not values to pass to the server. Read the docs on what the init object is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

Comment: Why would you expect the second one to work at all? `api_key` and `field` are [not valid options for `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters)

Comment: If you want the second one to work, you have to put the data in the `body` key , as FormData or UrlSearchParams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second way, you passed the `option` parameter (with "api_key" and "field"), not queryParams as you meant.

You can change it to work using `URLSearchParams`

```
fetch('https://api.peopledatalabs.com/v5/autocomplete?' + new URLSearchParams({
    api_key: "someAPIKey",
    field: "location",
}))
```